# Automate process of grabbing elements from a webpage

Tags: web-scraping, automation, automated-tests, element, html

I'm looking to automate test cases for webpage development using Robot Framework. I have about 5000 test case strings that describe pathways to different page elements. Now I'm going to be going through and grabbing specific "id" or "css selector" within the webpage for automation. My default option is to manually inspect each button, link, table etc. and enter it into a huge spreadsheet for automation, but I feel like there must be a less arduous method to extracting the elements.

I've looked into different options and the closest thing I can find to a solution is python webscraping, but from what I understand webscraping requires the elements are already defined and your goal is extract *information* rather than the actual *elements*.

Does anyone have a solution that might be a bit less tedious than inspecting 5000 webpage elements? ;)

Comment: You should add a  bit of source code to explain the problem.

Comment: Thanks for responding. As of right now I actually have no source code. I'm manually going to a webpage that's being built out, inspecting the different, interactable elements (i.e. buttons, links, table sorting toggles) of the page, and then copy and pasting each of these elements in a spreadsheet next to the pathway to recreate the action.

Comment: Do you really have 5000 unique web elements that can't be computed dynamically? For example, if you have a table of 50 rows by 10 columns, you really only need a single identifier for the table, and that will allow you to iterate over the rows and columns.  This sounds a lot like an [xy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem where you think the problem is how to grab 5000 elements, but the real problem is something different.

Answer (score 0):

If you can put your page in IFRAME, than you could probably use JS (in the parent) to wait until page is loaded and then get (all or specific) elements in the IFRAME.
That way you should be able to get all the elements of fully rendered page.

(never did this, but it should work)